# AngularJS blocks login access to inactive users

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, satellizer

I'am trying to block users with unactivated email tokens from accessing. Currently unactivated users can still log in and simply get an alert. This method uses the satellizer auth system, with a promise, then and a catch.

#### Here is my LoginCtrl

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myapp').controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, alert, auth, $state, $auth, $timeout) {

  $scope.submit = function () {
    $auth.login({
      email: $scope.email,
      password: $scope.password
    })
      .then(function(res) {
        var message = 'Thanks for coming back ' + res.data.user.email + '!';
        if (!res.data.user.active)
          message = 'Just a reminder, please activate your account soon :)';
        alert('success', 'Welcome', message);
        return null;
      })
      .then(function() {
        $timeout(function() {
          $state.go('main');
        });
      })
      .catch(handleError);
  }

  function handleError(err) {
    alert('warning', 'oops there is a problem!', err.message);
  }


});
```

I like to display an alert message "please activate first" at the same time block login. I appreciate your help. Basically, I want to check if the user is active, then login authorized, if not, login will not be possible.